# Python: print out the combinations of heads and tails based on binomial coefficient

Tags: python, python-3.x

Supposed we have an integer n = 3. Then we need to print out all the combination of "Heads" and "Tails" based on the binomial coefficients.

The result would be like the following.

```
for k = 0
{(“T”, “T”, “T”)}

for k = 1
{(“T”, “T”, “H”), (“T”, “H”, “T”), (“H”, “T”, “T”)}

for k = 2
{(“T”, “H”, “H”), (“H”, “H”, “T”), (“H”, “T”, “H”)}

for k = 3
{(“H”, “H”, “H”)}
```

No clue how to define the function to do this.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? It is nice to show some effort before coming up for answers, see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a straightforward solution using `itertools.combinations`:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def coin_flips(n, k):
    for c in combinations(range(n), k):
        out = ['H'] * n
        for i in c: out[i] = 'T'
        yield tuple(out)
```

Example:

```py
>>> for c in coin_flips(3, 2):
...     print(c)
... 
('T', 'T', 'H')
('T', 'H', 'T')
('H', 'T', 'T')
```